# How Can I Open Documents (PDF,PPTX,DOCX) On Android

Tags: java, android

I had made this for the open only pdf's on android .

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.setType("application/pdf");
    resultLauncher.launch(intent);
```

But I want it should be usable for the (pdf,pptx,docx,xlsx) for the my app . I tried this but it won't worked .

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        String[] mimeTypes =
                {"application/msword","application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", // .doc & .docx
                        "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint","application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation", // .ppt & .pptx
                        "application/vnd.ms-excel","application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", // .xls & .xlsx
                        "application/pdf",
                        "application/zip"};
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.setType(mimeTypes.length == 1 ? mimeTypes[0] : "*/*");
        resultLauncher.launch(intent);
```

Thanks .

Comment: What exactly did not work? What did you expect that would happen? And what happened instead?

Comment: so on my last code it worked for the all file's types but it should only for pdf pptx , docx , xlsx .

Comment: If you set mime type `*/*` then what do you expect?

Comment: aww , i get in online what i  do should